# How to write to a remote DB from an android app

Tags: mysql, android, amazon-rds

We have an android app that currently sends data to a php script which writes to a mysql DB on the same server.  We are thinking of using a scalable DB server e.g. FathomDB (which is just based on amazon RDS & rackspace) so that we can handle load increases easily.

The question is how does our android app write to these remote DBs? Do they have some kind of rest API, or allow you to have a php script similar to the one we have in place at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say most of services like these have a connector running on the web, like the one you are using. But some of the services you mention (for example amazon rds) have a native mysql connection. So you can connect using mysql to the server and run queries like you currently do in php. You can use ACL to ensure security in your application :)